# XMLHttpRequest doesn't works like $.ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I'm creating a crawler and I need to execute some javascript to get its return.

In both cases below the code works, but with `XMLHttpRequest` it doesn't return a specific part of HTML. I need to capture the element SELECT with id "*listaPartes*"

With `$.ajax` works, and with `XMLHttpRequest` it doesn't.

What's difference in the codes below?

- Using `$.ajax`

```js
// with AJAX
var url = 'http://www.stf.jus.br/portal/processo/listarProcessoParte.asp';
var data = {
    "dropmsgoption": "4",
    "numero": "andre",
    "partesAdvogadosRadio": "4",
};

 var response = $.ajax({type: 'POST',
                      url: url,
                      data: data,
                      async: false
                    });

return response.responseText;
```

- Using `XMLHttpRequest`

```js
// with XMLHttpRequest
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('POST', url, false);
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded')
var formData = new FormData(); 
formData.append('dropmsgoption', '4');
formData.append('numero', 'name');
formData.append('partesAdvogadosRadio', '4');
xhr.send(data);
return xhr.responseText;
```

Comment: The problem with both of them is first and foremost that's it's not really ajax at all, it's **synchronous**, which is a big no-no !

Comment: @adeneo I really need be synchronous

Answer (score 1):

On your penultimate line, you're doing

```
xhr.send(data);
```

When you're data variable is `formData`

So you should be doing

```
xhr.send(formData);
```

Comment: My bad, I wrote wrong in example. But in my code is correct this expression.